# Cloud function storage and deploy target

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using deploy targets on Firebase and everything is working fine except my Cloud functions.

1. The `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` env variable doesn't have the right values. The properties "databaseURL" and "storageBucket" are not the one I've configured the target to use
2. When I use `admin.database()` it doesn't use the right RTDB I've created and that I want to use
3. `functions.storage.object().onFinalize()` doesn't "watch" the right bucket

My `.firebaserc` file

```
{
    "projects": {
        "default": "hatch-rpg",
        "dev": "hatch-rpg"
    },
    "targets": {
        "hatch-rpg": {
            "hosting": {
                "shadra": [
                    "shadra"
                ]
            },
            "database": {
                "shadra": [
                    "hatch-shadra-dev"
                ]
            },
            "storage": {
                "shadra": [
                    "hatch-shadra-dev"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `firebase.json` file

```
{
    "firestore": {
        "rules": "firestore.rules",
        "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
    },
    "database": [
        { "target": "shadra", "rules": "database.rules.json" }
    ],
    "functions": {
        "predeploy": [
            "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
            "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
        ],
        "source": "functions"
    },
    "hosting": [
        {
            "target": "shadra",
            "public": "dist/shadra",
            "ignore": [
                "firebase.json",
                "**/.*",
                "**/node_modules/**"
            ],
            "rewrites": [
                {
                    "source": "**",
                    "destination": "/index.html"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "storage": [
        { "target": "shadra", "rules": "storage.rules" }
    ]
}
```

I'm initializing Firebase like this

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:
I have tried to override FIREBASE_CONFIG by doing `firebase functions:config:set firebase.databaseURL="hatch-shadra-dev.firebaseio.com" firebase.storageBucket="hatch-shadra-dev"` but it didn't worked because `Invalid config name firebase.databaseURL, cannot use upper case.` then tried without uppercase and got `Cannot set to reserved namespace firebase`
How can I override this FIREBASE_CONFIG ? or should I just not use it initialize manually firebase ?

Comment: What does `firebase functions:config:get firebase` return?

Comment: Thanks Philip. It returns `HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found`. Can I set the FIREBASE_CONFIG variable with config:set ? Is that the best practice ?

Comment: `FIREBASE_CONFIG` is something that is automatically populated. Read the following for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_environment_configuration_to_initialize_a_module

Comment: Yes I know... but how is that supposed to help ? I don't see how I can change this value. And if I can't how can I configure my Cloud functions to use my target database and storage ?

Comment: Are you trying to target another project? `firebase list` `firebase use [project_id]`

Comment: And initialize with `admin.initializeApp();`

Comment: I have 3 firebase projects. 1 for each env (dev, staging and prod). Now I'm working on dev only. So only 1 project. What I have is several target in my project, because I have several apps using the same database, storage, etc.

Comment: Also `admin.initializeApp();` is not the solution. As the documentation says "[...] is applied automatically when you initialize the Firebase Admin SDK with no arguments. If you are writing functions in JavaScript, initialize like this: `admin.initializeApp();`". So if I don't use argument it will use FIREBASE_CONFIG... which holds the wrong values

Comment: By default, each project contains its own Firebase resources (database, users, messaging, storage, hosting, etc).  If you're saying that you want several projects to all share the same resources, you will have to initialize the admin sdk with correct settings that point to the single project.  (But this is not normally a good idea.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how it's a bad practice. Firebase just released in 4.2.x "Multi-site hosting" just to do this kind of stuff. Here's a video of a use case https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrkFBmBFA6k

Comment: bug: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/433

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I did to fix this issue.

Maybe there's a better option or I'm just mis-using Firebase here.
Anyway, heres' the solution:

First, add some config to the project

```
firebase functions:config:set target.database="hatch-shadra-dev.firebaseio.com" target.bucket="hatch-shadra-dev"
```

Then use it in the Cloud function with admin.initializeApp()

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const config = functions.config();
admin.initializeApp({
  ...config.firebase,
  storageBucket: config.target.bucket,
  databaseURL: `https://${config.target.database}`
});
```