# Setting FIREBASE_CONFIG in windows

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to debug firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(....)

function in vscode in typescript.
But IDE throws below error every time I run this.

```
Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail
```

Comment: run the Firebase CLI command `firebase functions:config:get` to check what's currently stored in environment config for your project. And check if it's missing any environment data

Comment: @AroshaDeSilva it shows 2 key-value pairs. One is "someservice" and other is firebase "key".

Comment: I think there might be a problem with your environment configuration. This might be helpful [config-env](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Comment: @AroshaDeSilva yeah I've  tried setting env variable using firebase functions:config:set FIREBASE_CONFIG.databaseURL="h
ttps://xxxxx.firebaseio.com" FIREBASE_CONFIG.storageBucket="
xxxx.appspot.com" FIREBASE_CONFIG.projectId="xxxx"  But it didn't heip.

Comment: It says Invalid config name FIREBASE_CONFIG.databaseURL, cannot use upper case

Comment: is your databaseURL correct?

Comment: @AroshaDeSilva pls ignore the space in "https", it's just a typo

Comment: Similar problem has been reported in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201467/cloud-function-storage-and-deploy-target)